# False-positive on Android app - APK:RepMalware [Trj]||arep

Tags: android, malware, antivirus, trojan

Our app in Play Store has been out for a couple of years and we have never experienced malware detection before.

We are getting feedback from customers using Huawei, CAT and Samsung devices, detecting malware:

`APK:RepMalware [Trj]||arep`

We have gone through all dependencies none of them are marked as malisouse by
[Virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload) or any of the githubs have open issues regarding malware.

We have sweeped the web for answers and this seems to be an issue regarding multiple apps, frameworks and dependecies.

- [Lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/issues/1571)
- [GSMArena](https://www.gsmarena.com/no_our_android_app_doesnt_contain_a_virus-news-52893.php)
- [Eset Mobile Security](https://forum.eset.com/topic/32957-eset-mobile-security-as-a-threat-on-huawei-optimizer-for-android/)

Comment: I got a tip to send a false-positive-form to AVG and Avast, who basically are the same company - with the same virus-engine. To check if the malware is actually a threat.
Links: 
https://www.avg.com/en-us/false-positive-file-form#mac
https://www.avast.com/en-us/false-positive-file-form.php#pc

Comment: How did you check the dependencies? If you just upload the JAR file with class files inside that the virus scanner may work differently compared to an APK which contains DEX code. So netter create an empty dummy app an create an APK for each dependency where each dependency is included as only library. Then check those APKs on VirusTotal.